# iconfinder api: systematic `Origin header does not match`

Tags: authentication, jwt

I am trying to use iconfinder's api (v3). My goal is basically to reproduce their [demo application](http://iconfinder.github.io/api-demo/public/).

I am stuck at properly authenticating a request using JWT.

According to [the docs](https://developer.iconfinder.com/#json-web-token) I need to generate an access token on my backend, then use it in my javascript as Authorization header in my api request.

I successfully generate an access token in backend, and I use it in javascript to query the api.

However I systematically get a 401 response:

`{"code":"unauthorized","message":"Origin header does not match"}`

In the devtools I see the headers sent with my GET request:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiAiSldUIiwgImFsZyI6ICJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiA0NTcsICJleHAiOiAxNTQzNDI2NzczLCAiaXNzIjogImljb25maW5kZXIuY29tIiwgImlhdCI6IDE1NDM0MjYxNzN9.9YZfCmHZLaOEqVzUcn1DKipWRL4j0CunpnQd4QRvieY=
Origin: http://localhost:8081
Referer: http://localhost:8081/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36
```

The headers looked ok to me.
I also know my token is not 100% garbage because I get a different error if I use a wrong access token.

I figured this was because I had misconfigured my iconfinder api application:

[image: configuration for my iconfinder api application]

Now I tried a lot of things for the `domain restriction regex` in these settings, including:

- `$http://localhost:8081^`
- `$http://localhost:8081/^`
- `*`
- `.*`
- `$http://127.0.0.1:8081/^`
- `$http://127.0.0.1:8081^`
- A number of irrationale attempts :).

The documentation on iconfinder's api (that I know about) is not very comprehensive.

**What is wrong in my application configuration or in my request?**

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

you must write in regex:
http://localhost:8081/* - it will cover anything on your domain